# Multiple regression - python - statsmodels

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

I want to run a multiple linear regression on python using statsmodels. I have manage to learn how to do a simple linear regression using the next code.

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.html.widgets import interact
from IPython.html import widgets
import matplotlib 
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
Y = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4]
X = range(1,8)
Z=np.array([10.0, 8.0, 13.0, 9.0, 11.0, 14.0,1.0])+X
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(Y,X)
results = model.fit()
results.params
results.tvalues
print(results.summary())
```

So, now I want to run a model, for example: Y=a1X+a2Z+ constant. How can I do that, following the logic that I have got  until now in my code?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple linear regression in pandas statsmodels: ValueError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186436/multiple-linear-regression-in-pandas-statsmodels-valueerror)

Comment: Also, check out the [docs](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/index.html) for statsmodels.  They are well documented for the above question.