# Additional step for statsmodels Multiple Regression?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I am trying to do a simple multiply regression with time series data. To keep it simple, I am trying to prove concept with just 2 independent variables.

I have months from 4/30/15-5/31/2019  but have simplified to only 3 months for this problem and am using the below code to try replicate the statsmodels OLS samples.

```
example df:
X=pd.DataFrame({'ret1':[1,2,4]},['05/01/2019','05/02/2019','05/03/2019'])
y=pd.DataFrame({'ret1':[4,5,6],'ret2':[7,8,9]},['05/01/2019','05/02/2019','05/03/2019'])

model=sm.OLS(y,X)
results = model.fit()

#all of the above code works but when I try...

results.summary()

ValueError: shapes (3,2) and (3,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

When I look at the output error it seems to be failing trying to matrix multiply the two objects without transposing one of the objects first? When I attempted the same code using just one column of the dataframe as an independent variable it goes through. Is there something extra I need to do for multiple linear regression?

Comment: I think someone suggested this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186436/multiple-linear-regression-in-pandas-statsmodels-valueerror and that appears the same issue I have. Kind of backwards but it appears to have worked

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you appear to have your `X` and `y` variable assignments reversed. `y` should be a single variable (column), while `X` should be either a single variable (for simple regression) or multiple variables (for multiple regression).

```py
y=pd.DataFrame({'ret1':[1,2,4]},['05/01/2019','05/02/2019','05/03/2019'])
X=pd.DataFrame({'ret1':[4,5,6],'ret2':[7,8,9]},['05/01/2019','05/02/2019','05/03/2019'])

model=sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()
results.summary()
```

gives the result

```
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ret1           3.2222      0.774      4.164      0.150      -6.610      13.054
ret2          -1.7222      0.487     -3.533      0.176      -7.916       4.472
```

Note you will need to use `X = sm.add_constant(X)` to add a constant term if desired.